# Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ at the given point without eliminating the parameter

Tags: calculus

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ and $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$ at the given point without eliminating the parameter:

$x = \dfrac{t^2}{2} + 1$, and  $y = \dfrac{t^3}{3} - t$ at $t = 2$

I have a pic of it worked. Just stuck with $x = t = \sqrt{2x - 2}$  if that makes sense.

Comment: What is Y?Is it Y=1/3t^-t or 1/3^t^-t?Specify clearly

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted.

Comment: @Chris: please check my edit if it's ok.

Comment: @chris The parametric equations really, really need some parentheses so that it becomes clear which operations precede which. For the time being, if $x=X(t)$ and $y=Y(t)$, then ${{dy}\over{dx}}={{{dY}\over{dt}}\over{{dX}\over{dt}}}$.

Comment: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}$$  $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}$$  $$\frac{dt}{dx} = \left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}$=$\dfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$=$\dfrac{t^2-1}{t}$=$\dfrac{2^2-1}{2}$=$\dfrac{3}{2}$ for $t=2$

$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$=$\dfrac{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}}$=$\dfrac{t^2+1}{t^3}$=$\dfrac{2^2+1}{2^3}$=$\dfrac{5}{8}$ for $t=2$